# Is there a way to change the Heroku JVM Heap Size?

Tags: java, heroku

I am currently using the `Hobby` option for my web service which includes 512MB of app space. The error I keep running into `R14 Memory Quota Reached` errors after my service runs for a few hours. I think the problem is the JVM Heap Limit isn't set to 512Mb but the Heroku app limit IS, so Garbage collection isn't getting called when it gets near 512Mb since it's not technically close to out of memory.

Is there a way to change this so I don't get these errors?

Answer (score 3):

Try lowering your Java heap maximum to allow room for off-heap memory:

```
$ heroku config:set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Xmx256m"
```